# pseudocode about registers and clients

Tags: queue, pseudocode

I have projects that requires to simulate a market with 3 registers. Every second an amount of clients come to the registers and we assume that each clients takes 4 seconds to the register before he leaves. Now lets suppose that we get an input of all the customers and their arriving time: e.x: 0001122334455 which means that 3 customers enter at second 0, 2 at second 1 etc. What i need to find is the total time which need to serve all the customers now matter how many they are and also to find the average waiting time at the store.

Can someone come up with a pseudocode for this problem?

```
  while(flag){
  while(i<A.length-1){
  if(fifo[tail].isEmpty()) fifo[tail].put(A[i] +4);
  else{
  temp= fifo[tail].peek();
  fifo[tail].put(A[i]-temp+4);
  i++;
  }
  if(tail == a-1){
   tail=0;
  }else tail++;
  if(i>3){
  for(int q =0; q<a; q++){
  temp = fifo[q].peek();
  if(temp==i){
  fifo[q].get();
  }
  }   
  }
  }


 }
```

where A is the array which contains all the customers as numbers as required from the input, and fifo is the array of the registers with the get , put and peek(get the tail but not remove it) methods. I have no clue though how to find the total time an the average waiting time

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Please include code and a specific problem to which you would like a solution, or your answer is likely to be flagged and deleted.

Comment: I am thinking of taking each number alone and put it in an array and then create another array with the 3 registers.Each register will be a queue and by using a variable of time which will increase every second we will be adding and removing customers(numbers of the array) until all customers have entered and exited the registers. But the real problem is i have no clue how to find the total time it takes to serve them and also how to find the average waiting time